# Maximum call stack size exceeded while uploading large file using dropbox nodejs api

Tags: node.js, recursion, dropbox, dropbox-api, stack-size

I am running node server on ubuntu.
i am using dropbox module in nodejs.(https://www.npmjs.com/package/dropbox)

```
node -v = v0.10.38

npm -v = 1.4.28
```

I am using angularjs in front-end to upload file using (https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload) library.
Uploading small files < 25mb works fine. It is uploading to the server and uploading to dropbox. But when file if larger like (50mb). It is giving error.

```
(node) warning: Recursive process.nextTick detected. This will break in the next version of node. Please use setImmediate for recursive deferral.

RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded.
```

Here are relevant codes which i am using :

```
var client = new Dropbox.Client({
    "key": "XXXXXXXXXXX",
    "secret": "XXXXXXXXXXXX",
    "token": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXx",
    "uid": "XXXX"
});
    app.all('/test', function (req, res) {
        console.log(req.files); 
        var f = req.files.file;
        var dbx_file_stat;
        var short_url;
        var new_file_name = 'generate file name';
        fs.readFile(f.path, function (error, data) {
            if (error) {
                console.log('read error');
                return console.log(error);
            }
            client.writeFile(new_file_name, data, function (error, stat) {
                if (error) {
                    console.log('write error');
                    return console.log(error);
                }
                //stopReportingProgress();
                client.makeUrl(new_file_name, {downloadHack:true},function (error,url) {
                        if (error) {
                        return console.log(error);
                    }                                       
                    res.send("it works");                             
                });
            });
        });
    })
```

The Large files are uploading to the server but unable to upload on dropbox server.
I did some research . Some suggested to use (https://nodejs.org/api/timers.html#timers_setimmediate_callback_arg). But how to implement. what is causing this problem?
I also tried running app through  `node --stack-size=320000 app.js`
New error came after this ,

```
(node) warning: Recursive process.nextTick detected. This will break in the next version of node. Please use setImmediate for recursive deferral.
Segmentation fault
```

Comment: FYI (unrelated to the problem you're asking about), in case of an error in any of your 3 async operations, you are never sending a response back to the browser.

Comment: @jfriend00 The same code works for small files. I did more tests, found out the  client.writeFile function causing the problem. i dont understand. it is a standard library. Do i need to handle recursion on my own?

Comment: You apparently didn't understand my comment.  I'm saying that your error handling for your three async operations doesn't work properly.  That is not about the main question you posted about - it is an additional thing you should fix.

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce your error using the following code and a 75MB file. Perhaps the issue relates to the other parts of your app. (It looks like maybe you're using Express?)

```
var fs = require('fs'),
    dropbox = require('dropbox');

var client = new dropbox.Client({ token: "REDACTED" });

fs.readFile('testfile', function (error, data) {
    client.writeFile('testfile', data, function (error, stat) {
        if (error) {
            console.log('ERROR: ' + error);
        } else {
            console.log(stat);
        }
    });
});
```

If you're still able to reproduce the error, please share a smaller repro.

Comment: Hi, can you confirm your express version?  I tested my code in "express": "^5.0.0-alpha.1"

Comment: I didn't use Express. The above is the entire code I ran.

Comment: Strange, i tried the same. It is giving me same error. I believe its the server configuration problem. Can you share your ulimit -s and --stack-size value. Are you using ubuntu machine? i examined the ram usage using 'htop' . memory usage isnt going more than server  memory value.

Comment: To confirm, you're running exactly my code from above? I tried but was unable to find the old version of node you're on. Have you tried the latest version? My machine is a Macbook Pro, but I don't have it handy to check ulimit etc. (I guess it's just the default values on Yosemite.)

Comment: yep, exactly the same code with 55Mb file, I tried the same code on with latest node version on window machine and it works. i was avoiding to update node version on ubuntu because other servers also running on same version. Looks like i have to update the version. There might be the bug in old version. Will keep you updated.